# Java Stuck in For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm working on a Java project and for some reason I cannot understand why my code isn't going past a **for** loop.

```
float gain = 0;
float loss = 0;

for(int i = this.currentLine - 14; i < this.currentLine; i ++){
    StockLine pd = (StockLine) this.rows.get(i);
    gain += pd.getGain();
    loss += pd.getLoss();

    System.out.println(i);
}

System.out.println("WHY ISN'T THIS BEING PRINTED");
```

If I was to remove this three line it works as expected:

```
StockLine pd = (StockLine) this.rows.get(i);
gain += pd.getGain();
loss += pd.getLoss();
```

**this.rows** is an ArrayList with a large number of Objects (StockLine). About 200 elements.

Does Java have limit on the number of objects an ArrayList can hold?

The code is compiled and executed successfully with no warnings or errors. So I have no idea about what is going on here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Ahmad

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the quick reply everyone. Below is the current class. The only other portion of the project is reading a file line-by-line and calling the **file()** method below.

The method **getGain()** and **getLoss()** just returns a float.

This is the class **ReadStock** or **this**

```
package nyc.amin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadStock implements ReadFileInterface 
{
    private int currentLine = 0;
    private ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void file(String line)
    {
        if(this.currentLine == 0){
            this.currentLine ++;
            return;
        }

        String[] row = line.split(",");
        StockLine currentDay = new StockLine();
        currentDay.setDate(row[0]);
        currentDay.setTime(row[1]);
        currentDay.setOpen(row[2]);
        currentDay.setHigh(row[3]);
        currentDay.setLow(row[4]);
        currentDay.setClose(row[5]);
        currentDay.setVolume(row[6]);


        if(this.currentLine >= 2){
            StockLine previousDay = (StockLine) this.rows.get(this.rows.size() - 1);
            currentDay.setGainOrLoss(currentDay.getClose() - previousDay.getClose());

            if(this.currentLine == 15){
                float gain = 0;
                float loss = 0;

                for(int i = this.currentLine - 14; i < this.currentLine; i ++){
                    StockLine pd = (StockLine) this.rows.get(i);
                    gain += pd.getGain();
                    loss += pd.getLoss();

                    System.out.println(i);
                }

                System.out.println("WHY ISN'T THIS BEING PRINTED");
            }
        }



        this.rows.add(currentDay);
        this.currentLine ++;
    }

    @Override
    public void end()
    {
        //System.out.println("----------------");
        //System.out.println(this.rows.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Give us code that we can execute ourselves and that demonstrates the problem you encounter. More often than not, you will solve the issue yourself after correctly isolating everything.

Comment: Try running this with a debugger. Most likely you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: You need to share code for getGain() & getLoss();

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the console?

Comment: Update my question and added some code. There is no exceptions no other outputs besides whats printed by the for loop 1, 2, 3 4, 4 ... 13

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using a `raw ArrayList`? Are you using Java 1.4 or below? Because if not, then you should use `List<StockLine> rows = new ArrayList<>();` in java 7 or `List<StockLine> rows = new ArrayList<StockLine>();` in java 6

Comment: @Zhuinden No specific reason. Today is my first day using Java so I'm not sure what is best or not. I'll into those two suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very stupid when the loop gets to the currentLine it doesn't exist in the ArrayList. It doesn't throw and error or exceptions.

This line just needed to be changed:

```
for(int i = this.currentLine - 14; i < this.currentLine; i ++){
```

TO

```
for(int i = this.currentLine - 14; i < this.currentLine - 1; i ++){
```

Thank you for everyone that replied.

Answer (score -1):

this.currentline is evaluated every time around the loop.  If (as a side effect)
currentline changes, the loop may never terminate.

Comment: Without more information, this is just blindly guessing for possible reasons.

Comment: it's called "debugging" - start by imagining a way for the observed behavior to occur.

Comment: Just updated my post please see the code. **this.currentLine** isn't being updated until the bottom of the for loop parent function

Comment: the next likely cause is that your input has 15 or fewer lines, so the magic 15'th case that triggers the printing is never reached.  Note that this prints after the 16'th line is added, which might surprise you with it's non-printing if your input contains exactly 15 lines.